# How do I select a random value from an array in TestComplete?

Tags: arrays, random, textbox, jscript, testcomplete

I'm using JScript to test the character limit of a textbox, and also to make sure that numbers, characters, and special characters are accepted.

If I have an array like ("a", "2", "$", "D"), how can I choose one random value at a time?

I know about Math.round(Math.random()*9), but I don't want to return just an integer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
str = new Array("a", "2", "$", "D");
var result = str[Math.floor(Math.random()*str.length)];
textBox.Keys(result);
```